# Heroku doesnt load application, blank page

Tags: vue.js, heroku

I have a application in Vue.js that im trying to deploy on Heroku. The build and deploy were successfull, didnt return any errors.

But, when i open it on the browser, there are no componentes, only a blank page. The title its different to, as you can see at this image:

[Browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwGlB.png)

At Heroku `heroku log --tail` i get this message:
[Heroku log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXynB.png)

I believe that the problem is on the deploy, as locally in my machine its working correctly. But i didnt understand the error and dont know how to solve it.